# How should I display an XML document in a wxPython UI?

Tags: python, xml, wxpython, wxwidgets

I want to read/search in an XML document in a window of a wxPython application.

A lot of text editors will highlight the content and maybe have support for
block and unblock of XML elements.

Is there a component that provides at this sort of functionality in wxPython?

Comment: treebook may be what you are looking for to represent a tree structure ... or richtextctrl if you just want to color stuff ... or you could just render it with the ie_htmlwindow or whatever its called

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the wxPython demo of the StyledTextCtrl. It's in wx.stc. Anyway, the demo labeled StyledTextCtrl_2 shows how to create syntax highlighting for a Python file using self.SetLexer(stc.STC_LEX_PYTHON).

For XML, you would just need to change that line to self.SetLexer(stc.STC_LEX_XML). You should also look at PyShell / PyCrust or possibly Editra. The latter is a text editor created with wxPython that does this sort of thing.